# Tracking Wordpress Ninja Forms Form with Google Tag Manager

Tags: wordpress, google-tag-manager, ninja-forms

Im trying to track a ninja forms form submission with google tag manager.
unfortunatley ninja forms doesnt add id or class attributes to the form tag.
is there a way to add id or class to a ninja forms form or is there a way to find another selector in google tag manager? maybe a way to select the x path or the CSS Selector path ?

i cant track any form on this landing page, since there are other forms too, like search form and a signup form.

any help would be quiet nice!

Answer (score 0):

In Tag Manager create a tag and then in the trigger select FORM ID equals ninja_forms_form_1 (or whatever form number it is, check naming convention too in your ninja form), you can also add another trigger with page URL contains. In the tag make sure the action is related to a form submit.